# LibreOffice Calc - Get the value of a cell of the next empty row in calc

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a four-column table with multiple rows with headings `Weeks` `Amount` `Balance` and `True`.

How can I get the `Amount` of the row that the last column that doesn't equal `true`?

[image]

Comment: Is column D a value or a calculation, i.e., B*n* = C*n* ?

Comment: D is a value provided by the user